# How to get the entire list instead of only the first result? Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The following functions return only the first row of the database, would you please guide me get the entire rows please?

My Function :

```
        private List<Phrases_Clp> PhrasesStringToListPhrases_Clp(string phrases_codes)
        {
            List<Phrases_Clp> phrases_Clps = new List<Phrases_Clp>();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(phrases_codes))
            {
                if (phrases_codes.Contains(","))
                {
                    string[] listprhases = phrases_codes.Split(",");
                    foreach (var item in listprhases)
                    {
                        var mentiontoinsert = _context.Phrases_Clps.FirstOrDefault(m => 
                        m.Phrase_Numero == item);
                        phrases_Clps.Add(mentiontoinsert);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var mentiontoinsert = _context.Phrases_Clps.FirstOrDefault(m => 
                    m.Phrase_Numero == phrases_codes);
                    phrases_Clps.Add(mentiontoinsert);
                }

            }
            return phrases_Clps;
        }
```

**UPDATE :**

It still gives me the first result. I wonder if I should do changes in my view as I display information from another table which correspond the cell values in the current table.

Table Identification_Produit
[image: Table Identification_Produit]

Table Phrases Clp
[image: Table_Phrase_Clp]

Current Output:

[image: Current Output]

**Desired Output** is to display 'Mentions Dangers' of each Product.

GET:

```
       //GET: EvaluationRisque/Create
       [Authorize(Roles = "Administrateur, Modificateur")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            List<Models.dbo.equipements_protection.Equipement_Protection> listsequipement = _context.Equipement_Protections.ToList();
            Create_Viewbags();

            var model = new EvaluationRisquesViewModel();

            var produitUtiliseByProduitId = await _context.Identification_Produit.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            model.MentionsDanger = produitUtiliseByProduitId;

            model.List_Mentions_Danger = PhrasesStringToListPhrases_Clp(model.MentionsDanger.Mentions_Danger);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Bootstrap Model in the View Page:

```
<td>@foreach (var mention_danger in Model.List_Mentions_Danger)
     {
      <p> @mention_danger.Phrase_Numero : @mention_danger.Phrase_Libelle 
     </p>} 
</td>
```

Comment: `foreach (var mentiontoinsert in _context.Phrases_Clps.Where(m => m.Phrase_Numero == item))`

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions as early as possible.

Comment: You're using EF Core, the ORM, not ASP.NET Core, the web app framework.

Answer (score 4):

Change `FirstOrDefault(...)` to `.Where(...).ToList()` (or use `phrases_Clps.AddRange( _context.Phrases_Clps.Where(...))`).

But actually there is no need to make multiple requests to the database and you can skip conditional splitting, so something like following should work:

```cs
List<Phrases_Clp> phrases_Clps = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phrases_codes))
{
   string[] listprhases = phrases_codes.Split(","); // will be array with one item if there are no commas in string
   phrases_Clps = _context.Phrases_Clps
      .Where(m => listprhases.Contains(m.Phrase_Numero))
      .ToList();
}
return phrases_Clps ?? new List<Phrases_Clp>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using FirstOrDefault function in this line:

```
 var mentiontoinsert = _context.Phrases_Clps.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Phrase_Numero == item);
```

replace it with **Where** function.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking that to utilize the query as `IQueryable`.

**Updated:**

Thanks for @GuruStron (Guru/Sensei)'s opinion and for pointing out the issue from my previous answer.

In short,

1. Exit the function with an empty List if `phrases_codes` is an empty string or `null`.
2. Working with `IQueryable` to prepare the different search criteria and defer the execution.
3. Once the query is prepared, execute the query via `.ToList()`.

```cs
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(phrases_codes))
    return new List<Phrases_Clp>();

IQueryable<Phrases_Clp> query = _context.Phrases_Clps;

if (phrases_codes.Contains(","))
{
    string[] listprhases = phrases_codes.Split(",");

    query = query
        .Where(x => listprhases.Contains(x.Phrase_Numero));
}
else
{   
    query = query
        .Where(x => x.Phrase_Numero == phrases_codes);
}

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: You even don't need `AsQueryable()` here, just `IQueryable<Phrases_Clp> query = _context.Phrases_Clps;` should work.

Comment: Also note that your code breaks OP logic - for null or empty strings current OP code returns empty collection, while yours will return all records from the table.

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion, I revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my minimalist proposal

```
private List<Phrases_Clp> PhrasesStringToListPhrases_Clp(string phrases_codes)
{
     var listprhases = phrases_codes != null ? phrases_codes.Split(",") : new string[0];

     return _context.Phrases_Clps.Where(x => listprhases.Contains(x.Phrase_Numero)).ToList();
}
```